# Will there ever be processes that are shown by ps -ef and not ps -e?

Tags: linux, ps

I was under the impression that ps -e as root will display every process but several coworkers have claimed that the -ef flag is needed.

The man page seems to indicate that all -f changes is formatting, am I being pranked or is this a widespread myth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

Running either `ps -e` or `ps -ef` as root will show every process. The `f` flag just does full format listing as the man page states. If you examine the output, you'll see that the `f` only gives more columns including CMD, TIME, STIME, PPID, and UID.

`ps ax` will also show every process on the system but just with BSD syntax as the man page states.